# Typescript: Assign object Literal to typed variable / typeof object literal. Both possible?

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror, duck-typing

Given an type:

```
type MyType = {
   A: number | string
}
```

the following will raise an error (exactly as I want it):

```
const myValue1: MyType = {
   A: 123,
   B: "Oh!", // raises a type error, because I accidentally defined the property B
}
```

On the other hand, the following would give me the type of the object literal:

```
const myValue2 = {
   A: 123
}
const MyLiteralType = typeof myValue2; // {A: number}
```

Ideally I want to have both:

- strict checking when assigning to myValue (no additional properties allowed), and
- extracting the type of myValue as I defined it as ab object literal ({A: number})

Can I trick typescript to give me that, without having to explicitely to define a second type ({A: number}) ? A am out of ideas.

It seems I can only have one or the other:

- either assign an object literal to a typed variable and have strict type checking, or
- extract the type of the object literal, but no strict type checking (only duck typing).

May be I can, through some template magic, compare the two types (MyType and MyLiteralType) and raise an error when there are additional properties ?

Comment: Did you mean `type MyLiteralType = typeof myValue2; // {A: number}
` instead of `const MyLiteralType = typeof myValue2; // {A: number}
`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) was made for:

```
type MyType = {
   A: number | string
};
const myValue2 = {
   A: 123
} satisfies MyType;
const myValue1 = {
   A: 123,
   B: "Oh!", // raises a type error, because I accidentally defined the property B
} satisfies MyType;
type MyLiteralType = typeof myValue2; // {A: number}
```

<sup>([online demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=53&install-plugin=typescript-playground-link-shortener#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKuCCAXFAHYCuAtgEYQBOUAPlAM7A0CWxA5tgL4Dc2AMYB7YiyjkQANQCGAG1IQATFFSYc+IgEYlAZl7MZwNkwBmbCE1gIkArCLHAJ0+Yq2r02XFEJQdugBovXAAhIgAiAHkACwBCcICoAHokqBoZE0soGShQSChaGmEaROpBGVImaABJbMFBNgATCGJgeTkQKGbzYghG3OjoMCLIGlAoEIMmIxNzLLhESDs86DgAGTZgWnlFlFykYVNnWQVlPmTUtF8yKloeIA))</sup>